# Resize Google Maps when Tabs are triggered

Tags: jquery, google-maps, tabs, resize

Here is a more focused question to my issue.  I have 3 maps, in 3 tabs.  The first map shows, the other 2 do not. I realized i need to re-size the maps when the Tab is called.  But I am not sure where to place the resize code. Right now I am not getting any results:

```
 $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
      createMap();

})


function createMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.30, -97.70),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'),
    mapOptions);

    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas3'),
    mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map2.setCenter(30.30, -97.70);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map3.setCenter(30.30, -97.70);
  });

}
```

I am called the function on the click for the tabs, but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: On first glance, it looks like it should work.  Please construct a jsFiddle demo so we can see it fail.  Which code is inside your `document.ready` function?

Comment: I started digging through your page and I gave up.  I was thinking more along the lines of something stripped down to just the bare amount of code causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger the resize event when you click on the new tab. You'll need to pass an instance of the google map object into the event trigger.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
$('a.location-map').on('click', function (e) {
            setTimeout(function(){  initialize();  
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,
Load Map when page is loaded

```
$(function () { initializeMap();});
```

After that create click event for tab

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        initializeMap();
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    }, 1000);
                });
```